# Using While with For loop in url in python

Tags: python

I am trying to scrape some tables from a website.  The url has two parameters that keeps changing with every table - id value and an alpha value.  The example of the url is as follows:

http://resources.afaqs.com/index.html?id=123&category=AD+Agencies&alpha=A

I want to iterate through id and alpha value.  My code so far is as follows:

```
import csv
import bs4 as bs
import requests


data = ['1','2','3','7','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','W','X','Y','Z']
number = None


while number < 500:
    for i in data:
        url = "http://resources.afaqs.com/index.html?id="
        if number is not None:
            url += str(number) + "&category=AD+Agencies&alpha={}".format(i)
        print(url)

        if number is None:
            number = 1
        else:
            number += 1
```

This iterates the id number from 1 to 499 and for the alpha value A to Z sequentially.  Whereas what I want is: for every id, I want the alpha values to be iterated from A to Z.

I tried changing the for loop by using it before while loop, for loop before print url, etc...each of these combinations gives odd results and not the one that I wanted.

Can someone help please?

Comment: Why are you setting number to `None` and then doing a check, why not just set `number` to `0` and then you can do a simple `if not number` check and do your `number += 1` without any extra `if` statements?

Comment: I don't understand why your code is not what you want.

Comment: Why do you have `1, 2, 3, 7` in your `data` list if you only want A to Z?

Comment: `number < 500` where `number` is `None` object <- it will raise `TypeError` in **Python 3**, so it looks like you are using **2.***

Comment: The alpha values does have 1,2,3,7

Comment: @Azat Ibrakov yes I am python 2.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use the `while` loop at all, use nested `for`:

```
url = "http://resources.afaqs.com/index.html?id={}&category=AD+Agencies&alpha={}"
for number in range(1,500):
    for i in data:
        print url.format(number, i)
```

Comment: Oh, and if you use only one-character entries in `data`, you might change it like this: `data = '1237ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'`

Comment: This feels much more Pythonic, I like

Answer (score 2):

assuming we need to iterate through ids and for each id iterate through uppercase latin letters we can write

```
from string import ascii_uppercase


def get_urls(number_stop):
    url = "http://resources.afaqs.com/index.html?id={}&category=AD+Agencies&alpha={}"
    urls = []
    for number in range(1, number_stop):
        for letter in ascii_uppercase:
            urls.append(url.format(number, letter))
    return urls
```

or using [generator](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-generator)

```
from string import ascii_uppercase


def generate_urls(number_stop):
    url = "http://resources.afaqs.com/index.html?id={}&category=AD+Agencies&alpha={}"
    for number in range(1, number_stop):
        for letter in ascii_uppercase:
            yield url.format(number, letter)
```

or finally using generator & [`product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to get rid of extra loop

```
from itertools import product
from string import ascii_uppercase


def generate_urls(number_stop):
    url = "http://resources.afaqs.com/index.html?id={}&category=AD+Agencies&alpha={}"
    for number, letter in product(range(1, number_stop),
                                  ascii_uppercase):
        yield url.format(number, letter)
```